# Linq query list of blob, memory usage

Tags: c#, linq, memory, blob

Hello fellow developers,

I'm trying to improve the export of a list of XML objects stored in BLOB format in an Oracle database, using a Linq query.

Sadly, one of the BLOB's is quite big and the memory usage grows up to 2 GB when I'm reading it. My `fileSet` object is an `IQueryable<myRecord>` object.
I tried

```
foreach (var file in fileSet){...}
```

and

```
var files = fileSet.ToList(); //This time the list is causing the memory load.
foreach(file in files){...}
```

and

```
var e = fileSet.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
while(e.MoveNext()){...}
```

But every time I hit the big record in the list, the ram is over used.
For the creation of the export I was looking for some code using `Buffer.BlockCopy` but because of the memory overcharge there is no point going further in this direction, if you have some idea how to reduce the memory usage or to lazy load each blob :(

Comment: Do you need to load a blob in your processing or it is just happen because the record definition of fileSet has this blob field?

Comment: @SergeyL I need the blob, this software is loading these blob and exporting them in xls files, it's basically xml inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally because I couldn't manage to have something light in memory with linq, I used an `OracleCommand` to stream the xml file, after I've got the ID of the file with linq.

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      var blob = reader.GetOracleLob(0);
      var buffer = new byte[128];
      using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
      {
          blob.CopyTo(fs);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There're several solutions:
1) add AsNoTracking() to your query.

```
fileSet.AsNoTracking() or fileSet.AsNoTracking().Where(...)
```

AsNoTracking() helps the garbage collector to free records because the records will not be cached in the database context. But as you know it does not act immediately, you still may have a local increase in consumed memory.

2) you may create a separate definition of your record that does not include the blob field and get the list of files by it or use a select expression it may help also but you should check how it is translated to the sql

```
fileSet.AsNoTracking().Select(x=>new { x.Id, x.Name })
```

Then processing each record you will be explicitly get a blob

```
var myblob = model.Database
    .SqlQuery<string>("select myblob from mytable where id=@id", 
         new SqlParameter("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int) { Value = myId })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var myBlob = fileSet
       .AsNoTracking()
       .Select(x=>new { x.Blob )
       .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ConfigId=myId);
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer.
Because I'm still on EF 4.0 I don't have acces to `AsNoTracking()`
So i tried `fileSet.SetMergeOption(MergeOption.NoTracking);`
But it didn't change the result, still a lot of memory usage after the object with the big blob is loaded.
But I will continue to search about this, and maybe update my EF, if my manager is ok ^^